# Want to know the Xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xpath

**This is the HTML content**

```
<dd id="_offers2" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="wholesale nowrap ">
    <span itemprop="price" class="Hover   Hover   Hover">$46.29</span>
    / each
    <meta itemprop="pricecurrency" content="USD" class="">
</dd>
```

I want to capture "**$46.29**" and "**/each**" separately, to get the Xpath For both.

Comment: sorry Machi now its visible

Comment: I made it da... Anyway. I don't think you will be able to select the `/each`.

Comment: `/dd/text()` and `/dd/span/text()` ?

Comment: @Andrey  using that xpath not able to select "/each " please suggest me any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get the **$46.29** :

`xpath = //dd/span[@itemprop='price']`

`var spanElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;`

This will get you the `span` element, now you can get the text of the element using :

`spanElement.textContent`

To get the **/each** :

Apply the same procedure described above to get `/each`. This time you will need to fetch the `dd` element instead of `span`, so your xpath will be `//dd`